# Determining what is shown in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a web browser type application using a textbox as an address bar and an iframe as a web content host. Upon entering an address in the textbox, the content in the iframe changes and is working properly. When the client clicks on a link in the iframe, the text in the address bar should change according to the content in the iframe - how can I do this?

For example: To begin with, **www.microsoft.com** is in the textbox and the corresponding page is in the iframe. If I click on a link such as products, the text box text should change to the page in the iframe.

Comment: you are telling that already the question having three answers,,,but one also not suits for my answer.                                   this is not answer i am looking for ,i am looking to get status for iframe and to get that status to my addressbar.....                        document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the onload event on your iframe to know when url has been changed. Then read the src attribute and update your textbox.

Comment: same thing i have done....but always i am getting same url what i have given first,in onload() event i am not getting the changed url.

Comment: Are you using iframe.src or iframe.getAttribute("src") ?

Comment: both i used, but when i inspect elemet also i am getting src as same what i have assigned first

Comment: After a few search, there is no way to get the url when the iframe url is not from the same domain. For security reasons. You can only get the initial url set as html attribute.

Comment: so there is no solution for that problem guys..please give me any solution of other way.....Mr.sebcap26